# Focus lost in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, focus, internet-explorer-11

I have an input with a permanent focus that works fine in every browser except for Internet Explorer 11. I have tried several things to fix it, but they haven't worked. How could it be fixed?

Comment: Got any code or a working URL?

Comment: I already solve it!. Thank you